# How to find the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n+3}$; in terms of eulers number

Tags: real-analysis

I have been struggling to find this limit because the desired form of the answer was to be "multiple" of e (eulers number). 
this confused me i have found the limit to be infinity. not a multiple of e.
any help would be great especially if i am not understanding one of the various theorems that are involved in Real Analysis.
thanks

Comment: do you mean this 
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{n+3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{n+3} =\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{2n}\right]^\frac{n+3}{2n} $$

we know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{2n} =e$$

and $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{n+3}{2n}=\frac12$$

so $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{n+3} =\sqrt e$$

Answer (score 5):

We assume that the expression is 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n+3}.$$
This is
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^3 \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}\right)^{1/2}.$$

Using the fact that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=e$, we find that our limit is $e^{1/2}$.

Comment: is there a general algorithm for this type of question Andre?

Comment: It depends what you are allowed to assume. It is a basic fact that ($\ast$): $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$. One manipulates exponents to get ($\ast$) to appear.

Comment: Andre: thank you, i knew of the fact that (*) goes e, however no one has showed me that the (*) goes to e^n this is much more clear to me now!

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{n+3} =\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right)^{2n}\right]^\frac{n+3}{2n} $$

Now use the fact that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {2n}\right) =e$$ and the fact that $\lim_n \frac{n+3}{2n}$ is easy to calculate...

Comment: what is the relevance of creating the exponent n+3/2n...i want to understand this relevance N.S.

Comment: @Dom That is irrelevant, what is relevant is to get $2n$ as the power. The key here is that if $y_n$ is a sequence which goes to $\infty$ we know from the definition of $e$ (maybe combined with few extra things for the case $y_n$ is not integer, that $$\lim_n \left( 1+\frac{1}{y_n}\right)^{y_n} =e$$  So what I did was to isolate $$\left( 1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}$$ in the limit..To do that I wrote $(n+3)=(2n) (\frac{n+3}{2n})$.

Comment: @Dom In general, if $x_n, y_n \to \infty$ and you need to calculate $$\lim\left( 1+\frac{1}{y_n}\right)^{x_n}$$ the trick is to write $$\left( 1+\frac{1}{y_n}\right)^{x_n} =\left[ \left( 1+\frac{1}{y_n}\right)^{y_n}\right]^{\frac{x_n}{y_n}} $$ This way we know that the inside limit is $e$, and all we ahve to do is calculate $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ which is typically a much easier limit to calculate.